# How to set lightning:datatable fixed column widths

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-datatable

I'm trying to set the column widths for `lightning:datatable`, but I don't see anywhere in the documentation on how to do this.  I was thinking of tinkering with `minColumnWidth` and `maxColumnWidth` and see if it would auto-adjust to my liking, but as of August 2018, [this functionality is broken](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018C5BQAU)

I have a datatable that has many columns that can be very skinny, while other columns should be much bigger.  Right now, everytime the page loads, the column widths are evenly distributed.

Comment: I had used these attributes in the past and it worked fine (and quite sure it does not work now because of the known issue :)). Not sure if there's any other way that you can fix the widths.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `initialWidth` property of the column to set the width when it is rendered. It can still be resized.

```
[
    { label: 'Message', fieldName: 'Description', type: 'text' },
    {   
        type:  'button',
        initialWidth: 34,
        typeAttributes: {
            iconName: 'utility:new_window',
            name: 'newWindow', 
            title: 'Popout Window', 
            disabled: false, 
            value: 'test'
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: `initialWidth` worked like a dream. Thank you!

Comment: Does the framework take care of responsiveness? It doesn't seem we need to use media queries, so I was curious about that.

Comment: Worth noting the same attributes here also work for LWC datatables.  I just confirmed with `initialWidth`

Answer (score 1):

we ran too into this bug too in LWC, possible workaround is to query datatable object and set 'minColumnWidth' dynamically- but this will apply min width for all columns without explicitly set 'initialWidth' and assumes default min width is 50 as per documentation

```
columnMinWidthSet = false;

    renderedCallback() { 
        if(!this.columnMinWidthSet){
            const someDataTable = this.template.querySelector('.dataTableClassName');
            if(someDataTable ){            
                someDataTable.minColumnWidth = someDataTable.minColumnWidth <= 50 ? 100 : someDataTable.minColumnWidth;
                this.columnMinWidthSet = true;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use your Lightning:DataTable inside Div Tag and Apply the SLDS Stlying.You can't control the Column width of DataTable Directly.

You need to use SLDS for Div and it will show accordingly.PFB the Code.

`<div style="slds-col slds-size_2-of-8">
  <lightning:datatable data="{!v.mydata}" columns="{!v.mycolumns}" keyField="id" hideCheckboxColumn="true" onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"/> 
 </div>`

Comment: You're suggesting to put a grid / layout around the datatable.  I need the widths of the columns themselves of the datatable to be adjusted